# Can Microsoft XNA run on Windows 10?

Tags: c#, xna, windows-10

I have created a game using C# and Microsoft XNA 4.0. It works on fine on Windows 8 and 8.1, but my friend tried downloading it for a computer running Windows 10 and found that it wouldn't open. It wouldn't even appear in Task Manager when opening it was attempted. The computer in question has the Microsoft XNA Framework Redistributable 4.0 installed on it, so it should be working. Is Windows 10 simply not compatible with XNA?

Comment: Can't answer your question, but I recommend get away from XNA, it's a dead technology. http://www.gamasutra.com/view/news/185894/Its_official_XNA_is_dead.php

Comment: @Gusman But even though it's not being updated any further, it's still a useful development tool as it is, right?

Comment: The problem is you got stuck at DX9, and any bug you find will not be recoverable, there is MonoGame (http://www.monogame.net/) which is a reimplementation of XNA in Open source and it's portable to a ton of platforms, so it may be a good try. OR if you want to go to something a bit lower level but much more powerful use OpenTK or SharpDX

Comment: You could try running the application under Windows 7 compatibility.

Comment: @ManoDestra My friend tried running the application with both Windows 7 and Windows 8 compatibility and then tried running it as administrator. None of these solutions worked either.

Answer (score 7):

XNA is no longer supported on newer versions of windows, it was discontinued and isn't supported on platforms newer than Windows 7. Luckily there is an open source implementation of XNA which is essentially the exact same thing and that is currently supported on all windows versions. It's called "MonoGame", here's the link to their website:

http://www.monogame.net/

Comment: I've heard of MonoGame which uses the same code as XNA. Just to check: If I were to copy all of the code in the original XNA game into a new MonoGame project, would it work exactly the same as it did in the original game or would there be some errors or changes that are unique to MonoGame? And would I need to have some kind of MonoGame redistributable installed on a computer in order run it, similar to the XNA redistributable?

Comment: In terms of code, you would need to do some refactoring. For example in XNA I believe the syntax for loading in an image was "content.load", whereas in MonoGame the syntax is "asset.load". So I would say about 80 to 90 percent of your code will not need to change, just the specific API calls which are different. As far as redistributables go, no, MonoGame should work as a standalone framework as is. They did have some issues in older versions with the content loader in terms of the .XMB files however this has been fixed.

Comment: actually this could not be any farther from the truth. the xna redist is still downloadable on their site and I develop with xna on Windows 10 just fine.yes support was dropped but it still works perfectly fine on newer windows.

Answer (score 2):

Some updates:

On March 14, 2016, ID@Xbox announced that MonoGame is coming to Xbox One:
* https://mobile.twitter.com/ID_Xbox/status/709402975051980800

In the FB group Xbox One Indie Devs, Tom Spilman from the MonoGame team had some information to add, more info coming soon.
* https://www.facebook.com/groups/XboxOneIndieDevs/permalink/852775944827686/

Stay tuned to the Twitter account and FB group mentioned above, for new info when available.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a older post but just for those looking for an option like I was today (this post is still a top hit in google) its a bit of work to get setup, but XNA will in fact run on windows 10 just fine, and there is a way to actually use Visual Studio 2017 with XNA just fine as well:

http://flatredball.com/visual-studio-2017-xna-setup/

so if you have code for XNA or like the XNA framework (Like I do, I prefer the pure c# way not c# to some other bloated bridge like Unity) for 2D games then this will be your savior.

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 2):

XNA does work on Windows 10 and even Windows 11. In 2021 I released a game using XNA Framework and it works but the user will have to install XNA Redistributable 4.0 for the game to run on their system so that's not ideal.

But then I ported my game to **FNA Framework** which is an open-source, identical, reimplementation of XNA. My codebase required almost no changes to work under FNA so I highy recommend it to you.

FNA requires no additional library installation. The DLLs need to be in the same directory with your executable and it will work.

You can see my game here if you are curious about the subject: https://cyon4d.itch.io/cozy-days

Answer (score 1):

To add on what x2kpb said, your best bet at this point is to look at MonoGame for certain platforms, and [FNA](http://www.davevoyles.com/indie-dev-podcast-episode-25-ethan-lee-fna/) for others.

XNA, in its pure form, will not work as a new Windows 10 application. The platform to bring win32 (XNA) games to Win10 is called **[Project Centennial](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/2-692)**

Both Xbox One and Windows 10 will support MonoGame, [per this video at last year's BUILD conference.](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/2-637)